# Set a static private IP with systemd-networkd on arch linux

Tags: linux, networking, ip, arch-linux

I am using Arch linux and I want to have a static private IP that is always `192.168.1.10`.
How do I do this? I am using systemd-networkd and I can achieve the functionality I want by running `sudo ip address add 192.168.1.10/24 broadcast + dev wlan0` however this doesn't work upon a reboot. Help would be greatly appreciated.

Here is the current output of `ip addr`:

```
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: enp0s31f6: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST> mtu 1500 qdisc noop state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 48:2a:e3:7a:4e:49 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
4: wlan0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether b8:9a:2a:6f:88:49 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.1.143/24 scope global dynamic noprefixroute wlan0
       valid_lft 83499sec preferred_lft 83499sec
    inet6 fe80::ba9a:2aff:fe6f:8849/64 scope link
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

Comment: What `.network` configuration have you tried so far?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @user1686 I have tried this: `
[Match]
Name=wlan0

[Network]
DHCP=no
Gateway=192.168.1.1
Address=192.168.1.10/24
`